# Snowflake warehouse utilization in new snowsight UI?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The Snowflake documentation says I can view my warehouse utilization in the Snowflake Classic UI:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/warehouses-load-monitoring.html

[image]

Is this available in the new UI?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is available and it's explained [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-snowsight-admin.html#warehouse-activity).

It basically looks like this:

[image]